# Filling a drawline triangle with for loops

Tags: java, graphics, geometry, draw, fill

Hello I am a beginning programming student and I am stuck on for loops. My task is to fill a triangle (that I have already drawn) using a for loop. The idea is to keep drawing lines inside the triangle until it is filled.

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class OneLine extends JApplet
{
public void paint (Graphics page)
{

    page.drawLine (120,130,280,130);
    page.drawLine (120,130,200,65);
    page.drawLine (200,65,280,130);// 

}
}
```

This is the triangle I have so far. I was thinking that to fill it I would use a loop somewhat like

```
int x1=120;
int y1=130;
int x2=280;
int y2=130;
for (int x1>120 && int y1>130; page.drawLine x1-1,y1-1,x2-1,y2-1);
```

That doesn't look right at all however. I'm just learning loops, so I'm confused as to how to write the code. Can anyone help me out? I know there is a fill.polygon method but I am not supposed to use that here.

Comment: Do you have to fill the triangle by drawing lines? Otherwise you can use `fillPolygon()` for this.

Comment: Don't forget to call `super.paint(page)`, otherwise you are in for a bag of trouble

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a nice straight line between point (120, 0) and (280, 0) you can use (0, 130) as your stationary point and connect the dots in between (120, 0) and (280, 0). This might be easier to visualize on paper.

```
for(int a = 120; a <= 280; a++) {
     drawLine(a, 0, 0, 130);
}
```

So you are drawing a line from (0, 130) connecting to every point in between (120, 0) and (280, 0). By the time you cross from one side to the other. You will have filled your triangle.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying here. When I plug this straight in it gives me a slanted filled triangle. If I wanted to fill the triangle I drew, I would need to change the numbers up. Correct?